# rails css manifest file skips directives

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

rails newbie here. Can't get development machine to process `*= require ...` in application.css manifest file. In development.rb I have

```
config.assets.compress = false
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.debug = true
```

In app/assets/stylesheets there is application.css with

```
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
```

and the app.css.scss
If I request `http://localhost:3000/assets/app.css` The .scss is processed fine,
But the output application.css to the browser still has

```
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
```

in it, instead of the .scss file that is in the same directory. What do I need to enable the asset pipeline to process the require directives? bundle install is working fine. I have also tried with the precompile rake task with same results. It seems the directives are being ignored.

My include tag is `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>`
This is a Refinery site that I am trying to setup a development environment for.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Finally found out what was up. Had the wrong version of Ruby installed. Since this was an existing Rails application, the Gemfile specified gem versions which were I guess incompatible with ruby 2.0.0, which was what installed by default on my Ubuntu machine.

Fix:

```
rvm install 1.9.3
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```